# Powershell returns different results when it is executed using Farm Admin Account and other Account

Tags: powershell, query, farm-admin

Following PowerShell Script always returns null when I run the below script using Farm Account and the same script runs fine when it is run using other  account. 
Can you please suggest me what is wrong with code.

```
$CurrentSite = New-Object -Type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite -ArgumentList "http://mysharepointsite"
$CurrentWeb = $CurrentSite.OpenWeb()
@CurrentList = $CurrentWeb.GetList("ListName/ListUrl")

$spSourceItems = $CurrentList.Items | where {$_['ContentType'] -eq "MyContentType"}
if($spSourceItems -ne $null)
{
        #Executes when the script is run using Other Account
}
else        
{           
        #Executes when the script is run using Farm Admin Account       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check another account has permission to read list item.